# how to solve typeError when API calling

Tags: react-native

i have below json i want show image in List View and show images but its show me below error i'm learning react-native i was get function from example page but not success according to my requirement anyone help me this highly appreciate

> TypeError:undefined is not a function(evaluating 'data.map')

```
 async  getMoviesFromApi() {
  try {
    let response = await fetch(
      'http://example.com:2580/api/subcategories/1'
    );
    let responseJson = await response.json();
    return responseJson;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}

 render() {

  let data = this.getMoviesFromApi(); 
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    var navigationView = (
      <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#fff'}}>
        <Text style={{margin: 10, fontSize: 15, textAlign: 'left'}}>I'm in the Drawer!</Text>
      </View>
    );   
    return (

      <DrawerLayoutAndroid ref={'DRAWER_REF'}
        drawerWidth={300}
        drawerPosition={DrawerLayoutAndroid.positions.Left}
        renderNavigationView={() => navigationView}
        >
        <ScrollView style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column'}}>        
          {
            data.map((x) => {
              return(
                <View style={{width: '100%', height: 80, marginBottom: 20, backgroundColor: 'powderblue'}} >
              <Image source={{uri:x[0].imageurl}}
       style={{width: '100%', height: 80,}} />
                </View>

              ) 
            })
          }
          </ScrollView >
        </DrawerLayoutAndroid>


    );
  }
```

JSON

```
 [
      {
        "ID": 1,
        "imageurl": "http://example.com:2580/Images/speedometer-540-2501.png",
         "langType": 1 
      },
      {
        "ID": 2,
         "imageurl": "http://example.com:2580/Images/image2.png",
        "langType": 1
      }
      ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer that you use `componentDidMount` life-cycle method to fetch data.

```
componentDidMount() {
 fetch('http://example.com:2580/api/subcategories/1')
 .then(resp => resp.json())
 .then(json => this.setState({json});
}
```

Now you have JSON response in your components state.

You can then get it on `render()` -method with, `this.state.json`

This way you can achieve async rendering. You just need to handle case before you have any data in `state`.

Example.

```
render(){
 return(){
  this.state.json.length > 0 ?
    <div>{this.state.json.url}</div> :
    null
 }
}
```

Meaning before you have any data in state you render `null` and when you have data you render your JSON instead.

you should set initially your state with
`state = { json: []}` or `state = { json: null}`

I prefer usually setting it initially to `null` and show loader/spinner if it's null. Then depending if JSON data length is 0 I render example text `no data found` and otherwise requested data.

Answer (score 0):

Your function `getMoviesFromApi` is an asynchronous function, while `render` is not. So `data` is always null in your case.

Instead of calling `getMoviesFromApi` inside `render`, call it under `componentDidMount` and store data in component's state.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = { data: [] };
}

async componentDidMount() {
  const data = await this.getMoviesFromApi() || [];
  this.setState({ data: data });
}

render() {
  let data = this.state.data;
  // the rest remains the same
}
```